# SharePoint Configuration Failed cannot open WordAutionService DB

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, administration, central-administration, farm-admin

I was installing SharePoint 2010 in Windows 7 , SharePoint Configuration Wizard failed to open DB of WordAutmationService . Can any one help me in knowing what is the issue and why it encountered ,And how can I solve this issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Check that the Database WordAutomationServices_###### exists.
3. The error is indicating that the account spadmin\sharepointpc doesn't have enough permissions to complete the installation process.
4. Give the spadmin\sharepointpc account more permissions and execute the wizard again.

-Hope it helps.